# Bootstrap inverse (dark) style for tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

For navbars, we have a `navbar-inverse` class. Is there anything like that for tabs in bootstrap? Here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where can I find the exact colors that bootstrap uses for styling `navbar-inverse` classes?

Comment: Look at the Bootstrap CSS

Comment: ok, thanks for the help

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: Ok, I have to wait for 4 minutes though

Comment: Looks like I can't delete the question now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is nothing in Bootstrap 3.x for that, so you'd have to add custom CSS.

In **Bootstrap 4**, `navbar-inverse` has changed to `navbar-dark` which is still used for Navbar styling, but not for Navs (like nav-tabs). However, there are utility classes for [text and bg colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/). So, you could set the nav colors like this...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs bg-dark">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link text-light">Tab item</a></li>
</ul>
```